# Remove php extension in URL if URL does not contain keyword with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess rewrite condition to remove the .php extension from the address bar:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want this only to apply this rewrite if the URL doesn't contain a keyword. I've tried the following (below) and a few variants, and have had no success. I'm sure I'm missing a flag or some obvious regex, but I've been scratching my head for an hour thinking how to do it.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^((?!keyword).)*\.(php)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

The effect would be:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php => http://www.example.com/page
http://www.example.com/sub_folder/page.php => http://www.example.com/sub_folder/page
http://www.example.com/keyword/page.php => http://www.example.com/keyword/page.php
```

Comment: You almost had it: `RewriteRule ^(?!.*keyword)(.*)\.(php)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]`. Note that @anubhava's answer adding a conditional works just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !keyword [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept it as the answer in 5 minutes. I tried something similar to that (adding another RewriteCond) but I must have did it wrong.